# Read sqoop compressed snappy datafile using pyspark sql into data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, compression, sqoop, snappy

I am using Cloudera VM 5.8
getting an error while reading sqoop imported Avro file, compressed using snappy codec

```
conf = (SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("anoterApp1").set("spark.executor.memory", "1g"))
sc=SparkContext(conf= conf)
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlc.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/sqoopimported/avro/compressed/directorypath")
```

> getting following error:
>       py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o266.load.

the code works fine if I am not compressing the file using snappy codec

Answer (score 0):

try adding this configuration

```
 spark.conf.set("spark.sql.avro.compression.codec", "snappy")
```

Also this doc can be useful

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-avro.html